# Extract values between two specific html tag id-s in c# with linq or regex

Tags: c#, regex, linq, windows-store-apps

I need little help about how to extract some data between html tags.

i have the following html code

```
<select class="fields_search" onchange="document.location.href=this.value"name="someTextHere">                                               
   <option value='http://www.google.com' selected='selected'>Google</option>
   <option value='http://www.bing.com'>Bing</option>
   <option value='http://www.yahoo.com'>Yahoo</option>                  
 </select>

<option value="/city">choose city</option>
```

I want to extract only part between   because i need links and their description.
I have tried this Linq code:

```
var values = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("option") 
    .Select(n => new
        {
            Value = n.Attributes["value"].Value,
            Text = n.InnerText,
        })
    .ToList();
```

With that code i get all the links and their values but i also get the option value that is beneath closing tag 
This code will return ALL option values on entire web site. I don't want that. I only want option values that are in specific html tag.

How can i get something like this

```
var valuesBetweenTags = some code here  Linq or RegEx
```

and then

```
var valuesBetweenTags = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("option") 
    .Select(n => new
        {
            value = n.Attributes["value"].Value,
            Text = n.InnerText,
        })
    .ToList();
```

Note that i am trying this in Win8 StoreApp. In Win8 Store Apps there is no Html Agility Pack. WinRT doesn't support XPATH.

Comment: Which values are you trying to extract?

Comment: i am trying to extract links http://www.google.com, http://www.bing.com and their description

Answer (score 1):

First get "seleсt", and then get "options".
Something like this

```
List<dynamic[]> values = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("select")
   .Select(n =>
           n.Descendants("select")
           .Select(x => new
           {
               Value = n.Attributes["value"].Value,
               Text = n.InnerText,
           }).ToArray()
       )
.ToList();
```

Then get that "select" box values, that you need or limit "selects".

Comment: unfortunately i am getting an error "Error 1 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode' does not contain a definition for 'DocumentNode' and no extension method 'DocumentNode' accepting a first argument of type 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode' could be found"  This is a limitation of HtmlAgilityPack in WinRT i would say.

Comment: I can write for you a strict regular expression. But it will be a bad decision ...

Comment: Thank you. I tried your code but was geting another error so i looked into my code again and was able to find a solution. I will edit my first post and paste my new code there. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();

//load example
doc.LoadHtml("<html><body> <select  name=\"some_name\"><option>2_1</option><option>2_2</option></select> <select><option>2_1</option><option>2_2</option></select> </body></html>");

//selector
var options_nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//select[@name=\"some_name\"]//descendant::option");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string xml = "<root><select class=\"fields_search\" onchange=\"document.location.href=this.value\" name=\"someTextHere\">" +
    "<option value=\"http://www.google.com\" selected=\"selected\">Google</option>" +
    "<option value=\"http://www.bing.com\">Bing</option>" +
    "<option value=\"http://www.yahoo.com\">Yahoo</option>" +
    "</select>" +

    "<option value=\"/city\">choose city</option></root>";

XElement doc = XElement.Parse(xml);

var valuesBetweenTags = doc.Element("select").Elements("option")
    .Select(n => new
    {
        Value = n.Attribute("value").Value,
        Text = n.Value
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: i tried your code but i am geting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: just load the initial collection into `XDocument` or `XElement`

Answer (score 0):

I played around with my code some more time and i finally got a solution for my problem

This is the code that worked for me:

```
var values = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("option").Where(x => x.ParentNode.Name == "select" && x.ParentNode.Attributes["class"].Value == "fields_search")
         .Select(n => new
         {
             Value = n.Attributes["value"].Value,
             Text = n.InnerText,
         })
         .ToList();
```

Whit this code i am getting only option values that are in class "fields_search"